# Batch script calculate time diference in seconds

Tags: batch-file

I wonder how can i calculate de seconds between the current time and midnight time, for my script.

Im running w10 and my script needs a timeout -t X

Where X(s) = midnight-currentTime

Is there anyway i can do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You've mentioned 'your script' so post it and give us a fighting chance of answering based on the site procedure. Additionally, because times etc. are locally changeable, you would have to provide us with your specific date and time variable outputs. `ECHO=[%DATE%][%TIME%]`. We would also need to be sure if you are wanting to know how long until midnight or how long since midnight.

Comment: dbenham wrote an nice hybrid batch file that does great with date and time calculations. http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4847&start=9999#p47680

Comment: `for /f %%I in ('powershell "[int](new-timespan -end (get-date).addDays(1).date).totalseconds"') do set "secondsToMidnight=%%I"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To utilise powershell in a batch file I'd suggest:

```
For /F %%I In ('Powershell ^
    "[int](New-TimeSpan -End (Get-Date).AddDays(1).Date).TotalSeconds"'
) Do Timeout /T %%I
```

It will not be exact however due to the span between getting the powershell output and executing the timeout command.

Answer (score 0):

`%TIME%` will expand to HH:MM:SS.DD or HH:MM:SS,DD, where HH = hours, MM = Minutes, SS = seconds, and DD = fractional seconds.

I'm assuming we can ignore the fractional seconds DD.

The HH will be in 24 hour format, and may have a leading space or a leading 0.

The MM and SS may have a leading 0.

SET /A treats numbers with a leading 0 as octal, which is not what we want. So we simply need to convert any space into 0, and prefix each value with a 1.

So `for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:.," %%a in ("%time: =0%") do ...` will yield the following values:

```
1%%a = hours + 100
1%%b = minutes + 100
1%%c = seconds + 100
```

The rest is simple math

```
(24*60*60)-((((1%%a*60)+1%%b)*60)+1%%c)-((((100*60)+100)*60)+100)
simplifies to
86400 - ( ((1%%a*60+1%%b)*60+1%%c) - 366100 )
simplifies to
452500-(1%%a*60+1%%b)*60-1%%c
```

So the complete code becomes

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:.," %%a in (
  "%time: =0%"
) do set /a "SecondsUntilMidnight=452500-(1%%a*60+1%%b)*60-1%%c"
timeout /t %SecondsUntilMidnight%
```